# Login Mysql Java y Android studio no funciona (¿El error puede ser JSONObjectrequest?)

Tags: php, java, mysql, android, volley

Estoy intentando hacer un login en Android Studio utilizando java. Soy novato en android por lo que he seguido un tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dmszck6D6w&t=121s) al pie de la letra, por lo que me extraña que no funcione. He tratado de investigar y creo que puede ser que no se manda el JSONObjectrequest desde php. Pero no e hacerlo. También he buscado algún login hecho que utilice el JSONObjectrequest, pero no funcionaban correctamente. He probado varias cosas y nada. Me ha resultado imposible. Me gustaría saber si el problema si que es que no se recibe el JSONObjectrequest o no, y si es así como podría arreglarlo. Cualquier ayuda es útil. Muchas gracias.
El código de android studio es el siguiente:

```
import static android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Website.URL;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Login2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText nombreusuariologin, contraseñalogin;
    Button enviarlogin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login2);
        nombreusuariologin=findViewById(R.id.nombreusuariologin);
        contraseñalogin=findViewById(R.id.contraseñalogin);
        enviarlogin=findViewById(R.id.enviarlogin);

        enviarlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                validarUsuario("http://192.168.1.45/Registro/loginapp.php");
            }
        });
    }
    private void validarUsuario(String URL){
        StringRequest stringRequest=new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(!response.isEmpty()){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(Login2.this, "Usuario o contraseña incorrectos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Login2.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> parametros=new HashMap<String,String>();
                parametros.put("nombre",nombreusuariologin.getText().toString());
                parametros.put("password",contraseñalogin.getText().toString());
                return super.getParams();
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Y este el código php:

```
<?php
  require 'database.php';
if(!empty($_POST['nombre']) && !empty($_POST['password'])){
    $records = $conn->prepare('SELECT id, email, password, nombre FROM usuarios WHERE nombre = :nombre');
    $records->bindParam(':nombre', $_POST['nombre']);
    $records->execute();
    $results = $records->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $message ='';
    if (count($results)>0 && password_verify($_POST['password'], $results['password'])){
        $success = True;
        echo json_encode($success,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
      }else {
        $success = False;
        echo json_encode($success,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
      }
};
?>
```

En el LogCat aparece lo siguiente (no entiendo lo que quiere decir ya que soy novato todavía):

```
2022-02-15 18:04:31.410 7667-7806/? E/Volley: [595] dcg.a: Unexpected response code 404 for https://play-fe.googleapis.com/fdfe/deviceSettings
2022-02-15 18:04:31.411 7667-7806/? W/Finsky: [595] fjh.h(9): IOException while manually unzipping request.
2022-02-15 18:04:31.417 7667-7757/? E/Finsky: [572] luj.b(5): Error getting device settings.
    network time: 189, HTTP status code: 404, exception com.android.volley.ClientError
        at waj.hn(Unknown Source:4)
        at dbq.r(PG:2)
        at fam.r(PG:3)
        at dbj.run(PG:3)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
2022-02-15 18:04:31.418 7667-7775/? E/Finsky: [578] luc.b(1): Error while refreshing device settings: network time: 189, HTTP status code: 404, exception com.android.volley.ClientError. Retrying.
    network time: 189, HTTP status code: 404, exception com.android.volley.ClientError
        at waj.hn(Unknown Source:4)
        at dbq.r(PG:2)
        at fam.r(PG:3)
        at dbj.run(PG:3)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

Comment: No hay código Andrroid. Primero tienes que revisar si la petición obtiene un resultado.

Comment: @Jorgesys Lo siento. Juro recordar que si lo habí puesto pero cosas que pasan. Ya lo he subido. Gracias.

Comment: No has revisado si obtienes en verdad una respuesta en onResponse()?, las causas por las que no funcione pueden ser demasiadas, que dice el LogCat?

Comment: @Jorgesys Creo que puede ser que el onresponse no obtiene respuesta, ya que en el codigo hay un if que dice que si el onresponse esta vacio imprima una cosa e imprime esa cosa.  Creo que si mando algo y no se porque no se obtiene en onresponse ¿Cómo podría hacer que si obtenga algo?  PD: ya he actualizado el codigo y he añadido el LogCat por si puede ser útil. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Acabo de ver eliminaste 4 preguntas sobre lo mismo, te había comentado que la url http://192.168.1.45/Registro/loginapp.php debe estar visible en internet de lo contrario no va a funcionar si solo puedes ver la url en tu computadora.

Comment: @Jorgesys ¿Y que tengo que hacer para que la vea todo el mundo? ¿Publicarlo?

Comment: @Jorgesys No creo que sea eso de la URL, porque he hecho ya un registro de una forma similar que manda los datos por post y funciona perfectamente. Gracias.

Comment: Ok si lo hiciste en tu computadora no indica que va a funcionar en tu celular, ese es el problema.

Comment: ¿Qué permisos añadiste en tu `manifest`?

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo únicamente <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> ¿Debería haber añadido algún otro?

Comment: @Jorgesys Tienes razón. Pero, ¿me podrías decir cómo arreglar ese problema? ¿Acaso tendría que publicarlo si o si? ¿Habría otra solución? Agradecería que aparte de problemas me ayudes a conseguir soluciones. Gracias

Comment: Añade esto dentro dentro de tu `manifest`: `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` , esa línea es importante a partir de android 9. Como bien menciona Jorgesys, es probable que tu url no sea vista por los dispositivos. Puedes probar ingresando a la ip que pusiste desde tu móvil, si este no funciona pues sabrás que ese es el problema

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Ya he añadido esa línea en manifest. He probrado lo de la url, y es cierto que no funciona en mi movil. ¿que podría hacer para solucionarlo? ¿es necesario publicar la app? ¿Importa algo que lo haga desde el emulador de android studio? Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda y tu tiempo.

Comment: Puedes probar reemplazando tu ip por esta: **10.0.2.2** y nos comentas que tal.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Sigue igual. ¿No podría ser que estoy enviando un JSONObjectrequest desde PHP, y recibiendo un StringRequest en Android studio?

Comment: El problema está en que tu movil no está llegando a la url asignada. Sino puedes llegar a ella, no vas a poder hacer las pruebas. ¿La ip que estas asignando es la que ves en cmd con el command ipconfig?

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Sí.

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo Pero, ¿Puede ser que la IP intercalar su valor de un día para otro? Ya que un día copio la IP, y al día siguiente la reviso y es distinta. ¿O la estoy cogiendo mal (cojo la que se llama Ipv4)?